# HTMLのカスタムdata属性の値を配列で受け取りたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

こんなHTMLを

```
<select>
  <option data-select="a" value="A">A</option>
  <option data-select="b" value="B">B</option>
  <option data-select="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

jQueryでカスタムデータ属性の値を取得して配列で受け取りたい。

```
//期待する結果
["a","b","c"]
```

以下のコードを作成しましたが意図したデータを作成できませんでした。

```
var ary = $('[data-select]');
console.log( ary );
// 配列で [option, option, option] が返る

var str = $('[data-select]').data('select');
console.log( str );
// a のみが返る
```

ここからの処理の方法をご教示いただければ幸いです。
どうぞ、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

たぶん命令一発で配列とりたいってことなんだろうけど、
取得対象が複数のElementに渡ってるので無理な気がします。
下記のようにしないと駄目じゃないかなぁ

```js
var ary = $('[data-select]');
var str = [];
for(var n=0,len=ary.length;n<len;n++){
  str.push(ary[n].getAttribute('data-select'));
}

console.log( str );
console.log( str[0] );
console.log( str[1] );
console.log( str[2] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-select="a" value="A">A</option>
  <option data-select="b" value="B">B</option>
  <option data-select="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

また、data属性内で配列を使えないわけじゃないです。

```js
var str = $('select').data("select");
console.log( str );
console.log( str[0] );
console.log( str[1] );
console.log( str[2] );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-select='["a","b","c"]'>
  <option data-select="a" value="A">A</option>
  <option data-select="b" value="B">B</option>
  <option data-select="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事解決できました。

Answer (score 6):

特定のプロパティのみ抽出したい時は`.map()`メソッドを使うのがスマートかと。
余計な変数も置かずに済みます。

```js
var result = $("option").map(function(){
  return $(this).data('select');
}).toArray();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-select="a" value="A">A</option>
  <option data-select="b" value="B">B</option>
  <option data-select="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQueryの[`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)や[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)で要素のArrayが取得できるので、それを[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)で変換すればよいかと思います。

```js
var ary =
  $('[data-select]').toArray().map(
    function(option, index) {
      return option.dataset.select;
    }
  );

console.log(ary);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-select="a" value="A">A</option>
  <option data-select="b" value="B">B</option>
  <option data-select="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>
```